# how to sum values of a csv column ,that are type="None"

Tags: python, csv, nonetype

I do the sum of values of a column of a CSV file, the types of the values are "None", I used a filter, before summing the values of the column but I got this error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
out = pd.read_csv("file.csv",";")
f1=out['General Lighting'][1:]
k=sum(filter(None,chain.from_iterable(f1)))
print(k)
```

Comment: The error message says `str`, it doesn't say anything about `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter(None, ...)` removes any falsey elements from the iterable. The error message says that you're trying to add strings, so you need a filter that removes all strings, not just falsey ones (the only falsey strings are empty strings).

```
k = sum(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)), chain.from_iterable(f1)))
```

Comment: f1 contains a column retrieved from a CSV file..before adding the filter I got an error that says type 'none' cannot be added.I used your instruction now and this is the error :: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: I put back `chain.from_iterables()`, does that fix it?

Comment: unfortunately no, got this attribute error :                                                                            
  k = sum(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)), chain.from_iterables(f1))
AttributeError: type object 'itertools.chain' has no attribute 'from_iterables'

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should be `from_iterable` like in your code.

Comment: yes thank you I fixed it but I still got an error that the function isn't iterable  ::                     k= sum(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)), chain.from_iterable(f1))
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: I forgot the call to `filter()`